# A dime is tossed repeatedly until a head appears. Let N be the trial number on which this first head occurs. Then a nickel is tossed N times...

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

> A dime is tossed repeatedly until a head appears. Let N be the trial
>   number on which this first head occurs. Then a nickel is tossed N
>   times. Let X count the number of times that the nickel comes up tails.
>   Determine $Pr(X = x)$ and $E[X]$.

I can see that N is a geometric distribution with p=1/2. So,

$$P(N=n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$$ with $n \ge 1$ (or should it be $n \ge 0$?)

$$P(X=x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}{n \choose x}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$

Or should $n$ start from 0? Although, with 0, the sum would be greater than 1.

Then, should $E[X]$ be:

$$E[X] = \sum^\infty_{x=0}x\sum^\infty_{n=x+1}{n \choose x}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$

Or should it be $n=x$?

So as you can see, I'm having trouble with the boundary of $n$. Should it start from 1 or 0?

Comment: $n$ starts from 1 (the dime is always flipped at least once). $x$ starts from zero (the nickel might never come up tails). $n$ must be greater than or equal to $x$ but could indeed be equal to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 50% chance that there will be 1 trial (the dime lands on heads)

There is a 25% chance that there will be 2 trials (the dime lands on tails-heads)

There is a 12.5% chance that there will be 3 trials (the dime lands on tails-tails-heads)

There is a 6.25% chance that there will be 4 trials (the dime lands on tails-tails-tails-heads)

...

Does this help?